Gradient question on Wikipedia definition
Wikipedia has the following definition of gradient.  It seems like there are two definitions, are they the same?  I think the first is the gradient of a function.  What's confusing me is the dot product with $d\bf r$, and $d \bf r$ I'm assuming it is some infinitesimal change for each coordinate which I don't see in #2 where a single coordinate as $p$ is given.
#1
the gradient of a function $f(\mathbf{r})$ may be defined by:
$df=\nabla f \cdot d\mathbf{r}$
where $df$ is the total infinitesimal change in $f$ for an infinitesimal displacement  $d\mathbf{r}$, and is seen to be maximal when $d\mathbf{r}$ is in the direction of the gradient $\nabla f$.
#2
$\nabla f(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p) \\
 \vdots \\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)
\end{bmatrix}.$

$df(p) = \displaystyle{\sum\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)\,dx_i}$, and $d\mathbf r=\begin{bmatrix} dx_1\\ \vdots \\ dx_n\end{bmatrix}$. So the definitions are equivalent.

Is $\nabla f(p) = \nabla f \cdot d\mathbf{r}$?

That was my question.  I don't think they are equal and are describing different concepts.

No, the gradient is the gradient. Evaluating at $p$ is explicit in the second, but not in the first. I'll edit to make this clearer here.

Is dr an infinitesimal change in the arguments r?

It's the vector of those changes (whatever infinitesimal means), as I indicated in the answer, yes.

You could also write
$$
df_x(v)=\nabla f(x)\cdot v=\langle \nabla f(x),v\rangle.
$$
$df$ and $dr$ can here have the interpretation of linear functionals, $dr$ being the collection of coordinate functionals (on the tangent space), $dx_i(v)=v_i$.

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional real linear space and $U\subset E$ an open subset, the differential $f'(x_0)$ of the  real function $f$ defined on $U$ at point $x_0\in U$ is the linear map $h\mapsto f'(x_0)(h)$ from $E$ to $R$ such that $$f(x_0+h)-f'(x_0)(h)=\|h\|\epsilon(h)$$ where $\epsilon(h)\to_{h\to 0}0$ (and depends on $x_0$) and $\|h\|$ is any norm. In an other terms, $f'(x_0)$ is an element of the dual space $E^*$ of $E$. Now assume that furthermore $E$ is a Euclidean space (meaning equiped with an inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$). Then there is a natural, canonical, identification of $E^*$ with $E$: if $\theta: E\rightarrow R$ is linear then there exists a unique $y\in E$ such that $\theta(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$. It could be denoted $y=y_{\theta}$ and  actually $\theta\mapsto y_{\theta}$ is an isomorphism of $E^*$ to $E$ (Conversely for fixed $y\in E$  clearly $x\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle$ is a linear form, thus an element of $E^*$).
We come back to the link between differential and gradient, assuming now that $E$ is Euclidean. The gradient - a  vector, an element of $E$, sometimes denoted $\vec{\mathrm{grad}}(f)(x_0)$ or $\nabla(f) (x_0)$ satisfying therefore $$f(x_0+h)-\langle\nabla(f)(x_0),h\rangle=\|h\|\epsilon(h).$$ The gradient is an interesting geometrical object which is defined independently of any coordinate system.
Finally, we have not played with coordinates yet with $E=R^n$ the canonical Euclidean space with inner (or scalar) product $x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$ Fortunately, the coordinates of the gradient of $f$ at point $x_0\in R^n$ are nothing but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_0).$ $$f(x_0+h)-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_0)h_i=\|h\|\epsilon(h)$$ with $\|h\|^2=h_1^2+\cdots+h_n^2.$
The remaining point is the replacement of $h$ by $(dx_1,\ldots,dx_n)$. Well this notation is just convenient for a physicist intuition, and comes back to Leibnitz, but a bit troubling for a deep understanding of differentials and gradients.
In your notation $\langle x,y\rangle =x.y.$ Clearly the value of $$\h\mapsto \langle\nabla(f)(x_0),h\rangle$$ for $\|h\|=1$ is maximal when $h=\frac{\nabla(f)(x_0)}{\|\nabla(f)(x_0)\|}.$
